# failed to init database on Xunit with Sqlite

Tags: c#, .net, api, sqlite, asp.net-core

I created an initializer in my main project in which the database is generated and the information loaded.

Now I wanted to do this same process but for my test project, my question is how can I make an initializer for the tests?

If you want, I'll leave my github repository for clarity.

https://github.com/pedrohfk/MovieListAPI

Answer (score 0):

For EF-Core, you can either use in-memory or SQL-Lite to achieve your tests.

Check [Microsoft documentation on testing with sql lite here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/sqlite)

Basically what you need is to pass a new connection to the DBContext for your test:

```
public class SqliteInMemoryItemsControllerTest : ItemsControllerTest, IDisposable
{
    private readonly DbConnection _connection;

    public SqliteInMemoryItemsControllerTest()
        : base(
            new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ItemsContext>()
                .UseSqlite(CreateInMemoryDatabase())
                .Options)
    {
        _connection = RelationalOptionsExtension.Extract(ContextOptions).Connection;
    }

    private static DbConnection CreateInMemoryDatabase()
    {
        var connection = new SqliteConnection("Filename=:memory:");

        connection.Open();

        return connection;
    }

    public void Dispose() => _connection.Dispose();
}
```

Beware of the warnings:

> Using SQLite can be an effective way to test an EF Core application. However, problems can arise where SQLite behaves differently from other database systems.